# Entity Framework Core with undefined/dynamic columns

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a db with some tables in which items contains some localized string. The plan is to have an ID to a dedicated "Localization" table.

```
public class User
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public Localization Signature { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   ...
   public Localization Title { get; set; }

}

public class Localization
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string En { get; set; }
   public string Fr { get; set; }
   public string De { get; set; }
}
```

This works. But the goal is now to have a "dynamic" list of languages, so we could easy extend the localization to other languages.

I can solve this with a JSON field in which I serialize the languages string, but it has the disadvantage to lose the readability in any DB Viewer. So if possible, I would like to have real columns.

Is there any way to solve this use case with EF Core ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach this not by adding columns to the database (which requires a change to the DB structure) but by adding rows:

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   ...
   public string Title { get; set; }

}

public class Localization
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ItemId { get; set; }
   public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Then load item's title along the lines of:

```
item.Title = context.Localizations
    .Where(l => l.ItemId == item.Id && l.LanguageCode == "en")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

(You can also load Title in the same query where you load Item... that query is meant to be illustrative of the concept).